# How to do recursion function for views?

Tags: python, django, recursion, view

I have Categories and Sub-categories. I want do take all products from Category(and Sub-categories which belong this Category), and show for user.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title_of_category = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Підкатегорія', null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Категорія')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_of_category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Категорія"
        verbose_name_plural = "Категорії"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
class Category(models.Model):
     # YOUR CODE

     def children(self):
         # helper
         return self.category_set.all()

     def descendants(self):
         # your question function
         for child in self.children():
             if child.children():
                 return self.descendants()
             else:
                 return child
```

Comment: How can I call function (descendants) from views with request to Postgre?

Comment: show your template code. Default any methods in template called as object property.

Comment: I don't have template yet. I just wrote models and try to write views. I use Postgre, have table with Categories and Products. For example I have Category 'Cars' and subcategories 'Lexus' and 'Honda'. If user would click on 'Cars', I must to show him all products from Category 'Cars'. Help me please to do this.

Comment: you can try [listview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and you need start do it your self, and if you will have any troubles, create new question.